Strange Default Behavior For Python Dict Get Method
We recieve API requests from two versions of embedded systems as follows.
data = {"sender": "555-555-5555"} #new version

data = {"from": "555-555-5555"} #old version

To support backwards compatibility with older systems I wrote the code.
data.get("sender", data["from"]))
Question
When I pass the dict containing the key "sender" to it, I would expect it not to even evaluate the default value from the key "from", but instead it throws a KeyError for the key 'from'.
I know how to fix the issue, but why would python be evaluating the default when the key is present?
Note the following code.
{"sender": "111-111-1111"}.get("sender", {"from": "222-222-2222"}['from'])

This returns 111-111-1111 but if i change the key in the default, it fails with a KeyError

Related:  Avoid or delay evaluation of things which may not be used

I would expect it not to even evaluate the default value from the key "from"  <-- this expectation is incorrect, and I'm not really sure how to answer a question based on a false premise. Function arguments are evaluated before calling a function in Python.

@wim I guess what im asking is, from a techincal point of view, why would the default ever evaluate if its never needed? Additional or if conditions dont evaluate if the first one is true. e.g. if data['sender'] or data['from']: works fine

"Function arguments are evaluated before calling a function in Python" this seems to be the main deal. Seems specific to functions, but i dont really recall this in other languages.

Well, how can you predict whether a function argument is going to be needed or not? For dict.get it is easy to say, but in general it's impossible.

@wim i would think that the traceback would lead to inside the function where it would potentially be being used., not to where its being called. I just didnt know if i was crazy with it. haha

Yes, or is short-circuiting like that. So are conditional expressions, so you could do something like data["sender"] if "sender" in data else data["from"]. But imo the most Pythonic/readable approach would be just a simple helper function like def get_sender(data): with the compat logic in it.

@wim so or just behaves differently than the default arguments. And all arguments (almost) always evaluate. You can make it an answer and ill accept it if you want.

Not "almost" always evaluate - arguments are always evaluated before function calls, period. There are very few short-circuiting things in Python, the and/or and the conditional expressions are the only ones I can think of right now..

any(), all() and conditional expressions x = .. if .. else .. come to mind as alternate short-circuiting mechanisms.

When it needs to call data.get() as data.get('sender', data['from'])), it needs to pass values to both parameters, and thus it needs to compute data['from'].
This is not specific to Python, but the case in most languages. Values of parameters are evaluated first and passed to the function as arguments. Short-circuiting only happens automatically for operators that support it like or (see below).
You can get around that with something like:
result = _ if (_ := data.get('sender', None)) is not None else data['from']

Here, a value of None (assuming the value for data['sender'] would never be None otherwise) will trigger data['from'] to be evaluated, but it won't be evaluated otherwise, as you expect. The temporary variable _ is used to refer back to it on the same line, and named _ to indicate its temporary nature.
For a dictionary, this is more readable:
result = data['sender'] if 'sender' in data else data['from']

Perhaps you prefer:
result = data.get('sender', None)
if result is None:
    result = data['from']

Edit: if your data is 'truthy', you can also use:
result = data.get('sender', False) or data['from']

But this only works if any value you expect in data['sender'] evaluates to True. For example, '' would evaluate to False.

Yea I get how to fix it. Not a big issue. It was just confusing to me that the language didnt allow it how it was to begin with. I didnt know if i was going crazy or not.

If you think this answers your question, consider clicking the checkmark (even if you realised the answer previously). If you think the question didn't need to be asked, and shouldn't stick around for others, you can consider deleting it, but someone else may have the same issue. Either way, it's best not to leave your question unanswered, that will only waste the time of people answering, and will signal to people with the same issue that there is no answer here, when there is.

Don't think this answers the question and don't think the O.P. was asking for workarounds.

Beyond "When it needs to call data.get(), it needs to pass values to both parameters, and thus it needs to compute data['from']", what do you think is needed @wim? Happy to amend. I also don't think these are 'workarounds' but rather ways to do what OP does, more or less directly. If you have a better suggestion, please leave it here and I'm happy to add it - or provide another answer and I'll vote it up if I agree.

Only the first line attempts to answer the question, but it just states as fact and doesn't explain anything about why Python is designed that way. Too scant to be useful, I think. Everything below the first line is irrelevant and could be removed.

Hmm, I think the confirmation answers OP's question. It's not "how Python is designed", but rather how almost every language with function calls works. Only if the result of data['from'] could reasonably be expected to be some sort of 'future' would that not be the case.

Yes.. I could imagine a language where the function args were some sort of lazy-evaluated 'futures' like that, but that language is not Python. And some related proposals to add lazy features to the language were rejected (PEP 690)
